# Why is my redirect to action happening before the database processing step completes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the code of an Action method in the Controller as below. The newly saved 'todo item' would not be displayed after the SaveToDoItem was being called below. So I stepped through the code and realized that the redirect was happening asynchronously before the _agendaService.SaveToDoItem could finish its work to save the item in the DB.
Any idea how I can avoid this?

```
public ActionResult SaveToDoItem(int userId, string itemText, string dueDate, string userName)
    {
        _agendaService.SaveToDoItem(userId, itemText, dueDate);//This performs a DB process to save the item
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Agenda", userName); //Redirects to the Index action which retrieves all the existing items to display
    }

 public void SaveToDoItem(int userId, string itemText, string dueDate)
    {
        var toDoItem = new ToDoItem();
        toDoItem.UserId = userId;
        toDoItem.ItemText = itemText;
        toDoItem.DueDate = DateTime.Parse(dueDate);

        _toDoItemRepository.SaveToDoItem(toDoItem);
    }

    public void SaveToDoItem(ToDoItem toDoItem)
    {
        DbContext.Set<ToDoItem>().Add(toDoItem);
        DbContext.Save();
    }
```

I'm thinking it could also be related to the fact that the button has a type="submit" and is also being handled by an Ajax method thru

Comment: Show the code for `SaveToDoItem()`

Comment: Added the code as requested.

Comment: _I'm thinking it could also be related to the fact that the button has a type="submit" and is also being handled by an Ajax method_ -- Did you prevent default action on the form submission?

Comment: Your code is saving the data before you redirect. Perhaps your page is being cached. Try adding the `[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]` attribute to your `Index()` method.

Comment: @Jasen Yes I did just now and it worked! Thanks